# Is it standard to italicize more than one word in a definition?

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

When writing mathematical definitions, people often italicize the word being defined. For example,

> A set is called *closed* if $\ldots$

Is it standard to italicize multiple words in a single definition? For example,

> A *solution* for a set is $\dots$ A set is called *solveable* if a solution exists for that set.

Comment: It is not standard to italicize any words in a def'n. It's a matter of personal style, or to add emphasis. Italics are seldom used by pros writing for other pros as they expect their audience to completely digest every detail without any assistance.

Comment: That looks like two definitions, not one, although they are clearly related. In any case, if you choose italicize the first, it seems consistent to italicize the second as well.

Comment: Agreed with @DanielWainfleet that it's completely a personal choice. However, you should follow the same rule throughout the article. Many writers use bold or underline but I personally prefer italics for highlighting, looks more professional to me. The more flat, boring & lengthy it looks better it is. :P

Comment: Many writers precede a def'n with the word "Definition", often in a different font, or capitalized. This can make def'ns easier to find in a long tract, and alerts the reader that what follows is not a result or a claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard, because it is  helpful, to italicize the word being defined in a definition. In the present case, two words are being defined; so two italicizations are appropriate. The author chose, though, to put the two definitions under one heading since they are so closely related.